# In Ember, is there a way to forward one particular html attribute passed to a component to its inner children element?

Tags: ember.js

In Ember, is there a way to forward one particular html attribute passed to a component to its inner children element?

Let's say I have a button component defined and the button component has div wrapper around it.

```
//button.hbs
<div>
  <button>{{yield}}</button>
</div>
```

When I invoke the component with several html tags assigned

```
<Button class='my-button' type='submit'>Hello</Button>
```

I know I can use splattributes to assign all attributes to any elements in the component.

```
//button.hbs
<div>
  <button ...attributes>{{yield}}</button>
</div>
```

However, if I want to assign certain attributes separately to different elements, is there a way to do that?
So that the outcome is

```
<div class='my-button'>
  <button type=submit>
     Hello
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is. Usually we use arguments for cases like this, i.e.

```
<div class={{@divClass}}>
  <button ...attributes>{{yield}}</button>
</div>
```

and call it like

```
<Button @divClass='my-button' type='submit'>Hello</Button>
```

Comment: hmm I see. was hoping for one but i guess using arguments would be the way. Thanks!